# `flow_from_dataframe()` custom pre-processing

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision, medical-imaging

I'm trying to use the keras `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe()` method to generate image data on the fly as the dataset I'm working on is too large to load into memory in one go.

The source image data files are *DICOM* files, not supported by the `flow_from_dataframe()` method.

Is it possible to (easily) extend `flow_from_dataframe()` to handle DICOM (or other unsupported) images/input?

Perhaps a custom pre-processing function could be run on each unsupported file, returning a normalised (windowed/photometric corrected) numpy array, then allowing the `ImageDataGenerator` instance to proceed.

I could edit the source on my own installation but a general solution that can be used on vanilla keras is preferred, to ensure portability to other platforms (especially Kaggle)!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to this can be found on the Keras github issue tracker/feature requests: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13665

A custom data generator can be created based on `keras.utils.Sequence` as a superclass.